# Basic for loop in Octave expanded

Tags: for-loop, octave

For some reason I can't get over this in Octave:

```
for i=1:n
  y(2:(i+1))=y(2:(i+1))-x(i)*y(1:i)
end;
```

If I break it down in steps (suppose n=3), wouldn't the loop look like this:

```
 i=1
y(2)=y(2)-x(1)*y(1)
 i=2
y(2)=y(2)-x(2)*y(1)
y(3)=y(3)-x(2)*y(2)
 i=3
y(2)=y(2)-x(3)*y(1)
y(3)=y(3)-x(3)*y(2)
y(4)=y(4)-x(3)*y(3)
```

Well, I must be wrong because the results are not good when doing the loop step by step, but for the life of me I can't figure it out where. Can someone please help me?

Comment: x=[1,2,3] y=[1,0,0,0] With loop I get [1 -6 11 -6] and with step by step [1 -6 24 -72] which is strange since the 2nd value is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, forgive me my styling, I never used matrices/vector representations in Stack Overflow before. Anyway I hope this gives you an idea of how it internally works:

```
x = [1,2,3] 
y = [1,0,0,0]
```

**Step 1:**

the first loop will execute:

```
y(2)=y(2)-x(1)*y(1)
```

these are just scalar values, y(2) = 0, x(1) = 1, y(1) = 1.
So y(2) = 0-1*1 = -1, which means that the 2nd position in vector y will become -1.

resulting in `y = [1,-1,0,0]`

**Step 2:**

The next loop will execute

[image]

Here y(2,3) and y(1,2) are vectors of size 2, where the values are the ones that correspond with the position in y. After calculating the new vector `[-3,2]`
this will be assigned to the 2nd and 3th position in vector y. Resulting in the vector  `[1,-3,2,0]`.

**Step 3:**
Repeat the step 2 but this time use vectors of size 3, and replace the outcome with the 2,3,4 position in the y matrix results in the final vector y being: `[1,-6,11,-6]`

Comment: Now I get it, it's not working with single values, but with matrices given by (2:(i+1)). That was the missing link. Thank you for the answer. I can't vote up (yet), unfortunately, but I'l mark this as the answer.

Comment: Well, the correct terminology I believe is that they are vectors and not single values (scalars). But yep! Thanks!